# Crontab: Is it possible to activate `pyenv` as soon as reboot?

Tags: python, shell, cron, pyenv

Environment :  `Linux Ubuntu 16.04`, `pyenv`, 'pyenv-virtualenv`

What I want to automate is:

1. reboot
2. activate my virtual_environment as soon as reboot
3. run a command (in this case, `honcho start ~~`. `honcho` can be installed via `pip`) after that

What I tried:

1. In crontab list (`crontab -e`)
2. Add `@reboot sh /home/my_name/launch.sh`

**launch.sh**

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

pyenv activate super_crawler_project
sleep 5

cd /home/my_name/Workspace/super_crawler_project/  # Procfile.dev is located in /home/my_name/Workspace/super_crawler_project/
honcho start -f Procfile.dev $* > /home/my_name/django_log.txt 2>&1
```

When I reboot, there is an error log left in a `django_log.txt`:

`/home/my_name/launch_django.sh: 8: /home/my_name/launch_django.sh: honcho: not found`

But `honcho` is surely installed in my virtual environment.

However, when I run this command(`sh /home/my_name/launch_django.sh`) by myself in the Terminal, it works.

I think it can not activate my virtual environment...I don't know why it happened...

Need your advices. Thanks

**Edit**

I `export PATH` at the top of `launch.sh` but still can not find `honcho`.

**django_log.txt**

```
  1 pyenv: honcho: command not found
  2
  3 The `honcho' command exists in these Python versions:
  4   3.6.2/envs/super_crawler_project
  5   super_crawler_project
  6
```